# How to make the query to work?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cql, cql3

I have Cassandra version 2.0, and in it I am totally new in it, so the question...
I have table `T1`, with columns with names: 1,2,3...14 (for simplicity);
`Partitioning key` is column `1` , `2`;
`Clustering key` is column `3`, `1` , `5`;
I need to perform following query:

```
SELECT 1,2,7 FROM T1 where 2='A';
```

Column `2` is a flag, so values are repeating.
I get the following error:

```
Unable to execute CQL query: Partitioning column 2 cannot be restricted because the preceding column 1 is either not restricted or is restricted by a non-EQ relation
```

So what is the right way to do it? I really need to get the data that already filtered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to make sure I understand your schema, you have defined a table `T1`:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (
  1 INT,
  2 INT,
  3 INT,
  ...
  14 INT,
  PRIMARY ((1, 2), 3, 1, 5)
);
```

Correct?

If this is the case, then Cassandra **cannot** find the data to answer your CQL  query:

```
SELECT 1,2,7 FROM T1 where 2 = 'A';
```

because your query has not provided a value for column "1", without which Cassandra cannot compute the partition key (which requires, per your composite `PRIMARY KEY` definition, both columns "1" *and* "2"), and without that, it cannot determine where to look on which nodes in the ring.  By including "2" in your *partition key*, you are telling Cassandra that that data is **required** for determine where to store (and thus, where to *read*) that data.

For example, given your schema, this query *should* work:

```
SELECT 7 FROM T1 WHERE 1 = 'X' AND 2 = 'A';
```

since you are providing both values of your partition key.

@Caleb Rockcliffe has good advice, though, regarding the need for other, secondary/supplemental lookup mechanisms if the above table definition is a big part of your workload.  You may need to find some way to *first* lookup the values for "1" and "2", *then* issue your query.  *E.g.*:

```
CREATE TABLE T1_index (
  1 INT,
  2 INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (1, 2);
);
```

Given a value for "1", the above will provide *all* of the possible "2" values, through which you can then iterate:

```
SELECT 2 FROM T1_index WHERE 1 = 'X';
```

And then, for each "1" and "2" combination, you can *then* issue your query against table `T1`:

```
SELECT 7 FROM T1 WHERE 1 = 'X' AND 2 = 'A';
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This helps a lot, thank you. So does it mean that for the T1_index I need to do separate insert each time I insert to T1?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately.  Cassandra likes "denormalization", which effectively means _duplication_.  And it does not support foreign key constraints or things of that sort, so your application code needs to know to write to the (multiple) relevant tables, and to read from them.

Comment: I just spent some time trying this and that in my schema, and it seems I found a solution for my task based on what you've shown. So we can say that for each specific select query I need to create a separate table and include that table in inserting batch in my code, and that's fine as soon as these inserts are negligible rare, right? So Cassandra is for huge amount of reads and occasional inserts or updates, right? Again, I am new in it and completely RDBMS guy ) Is there any mechanism inside Cassandra to keep all that tables updated, instead of having multiples inserts in my code?

Comment: Actually, Cassandra is optimized for writes; it's the _reads_ which are expensive.  That's why the denormalization/duplication is useful; it helps improve Cassandra read latency.  And no, as far as I know, there's nothing built into Cassandra to automatically keep "related" tables updated based on a single write/insert.  A large part of Cassandra's speed and scaling abilities come from _not_ having that sort of schema relationships enforced by the database; those relationships are treated as "business" or "application" logic, and left to your application to handle.

Answer (score 1):

Your `WHERE` clause needs to include the first element of the partition key.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what error says. But how to get what I need the right way?

Comment: If you don't have any data modeling flexibility, and you need to cut across partitions, you might want to consider an indexing strategy. In vanilla Cassandra 2.0, that probably means using a secondary index, but there are a number of potential performance pitfalls to watch out for there. If this query is a big part of your read workload, you might want to consider modeling your data so that the key you're restricting is a prefix of the primary key.